# где находится ошибка

Tags: c#, .net-6

я пытался перевести код из js в c#

js

```
"use strict";
let crypto = require("crypto");

const sort_obj = function(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce(function (result, key) {
    result[key] = obj[key];
    return result;
  }, {});
}

const obj_to_string = function (obj) {
 obj = sort_obj(obj);
    let str = '';
    for (let p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            str += p + obj[p];
        }
    }
    return str;
}

const market_api_generate_signature = function(j, secret){
    const str_to_hash = obj_to_string(j) + secret
    //console.log(str_to_hash)
    const hashed = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(str_to_hash).digest('hex');
    //console.log(hashed)
    return hashed
}
const market_api_validate_signature = function(j, secret){
  const nl_sig = j["signature"]
  delete j["signature"]
  const our_sig = market_api_generate_signature(j, secret)
  return nl_sig === our_sig
}

let data = {
  "amount": 0.9,
  "username": "A49",
  "unique_id": 89968,
  "item_id": "E3yugw",
  "signature": "dc20a4d73447ac51689d6e03115aa135a8d734e610352dda818e830e70a60560"
}
let sign_valid = market_api_validate_signature(data, "key")
console.log(sign_valid)
```

c#

```
 internal class Testclass
    {
        public double amount;
        public string username;
        public int unique_id;
        public string signature;
        public string item_id;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"amount{amount.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))}item_id{item_id}signature{signature}unique_id{unique_id}username{username}";
        }
        public string market_api_generate_signature(string data, string key = "")
        {
            string str_to_hash = data + key;
            SHA256 shaM = new SHA256Managed();
            var sw = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(str_to_hash);
            var a = shaM.ComputeHash(sw);
            var aw = hexdigest(a);
            return aw;
        }

        public bool market_api_validate_signature(Testclass data, string secret)
        {
            var old_signature = data.signature;
            data.signature = string.Empty;
            var our_signature = market_api_generate_signature(data.ToString(), secret);
            var a = our_signature;
            return old_signature == our_signature;
        }

        static byte[] HashString(string text, string salt = "")
        {
            // Uses SHA256 to create the hash
            using (var sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed())
            {
                // Convert the string to a byte array first, to be processed
                byte[] textBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text + salt);
                byte[] hashBytes = sha.ComputeHash(textBytes);

                // Convert back to a string, removing the '-' that BitConverter adds
                string hash = BitConverter
                    .ToString(hashBytes)
                    .Replace("-", String.Empty);
                byte[] data = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(hash);
                return data;
            }
        }
        static string hexdigest(byte[] sha1result)
        {
            string hexaHash = "";
            foreach (byte b in sha1result)
            {
                hexaHash += String.Format("{0:x2}", b);
            }
            return hexaHash;
        }
    }
```

но у меня выводит false при проверке signature.

Изм.

Здесь я использую

```
 Testclass testclass = new Testclass();
            testclass.amount = 0.9;
            testclass.username = "A49";
            testclass.unique_id = 89968;
            testclass.item_id = "E3yugw";
            testclass.signature = "dc20a4d73447ac51689d6e03115aa135a8d734e610352dda818e830e70a60560";
          Console.WriteLine(testclass.market_api_validate_signature(testclass,"key"));
```

Comment: как именно проверяете?

Comment: @aepot с помощи метода market_api_validate_signature

Comment: Код покажите, который это все запускает, где код, который `выводит false при проверке signature`? Чтобы отредактировать вопрос, нажмите кнопку "Править" под ним. И второй раз при оформлении вопроса допускаете ту же ошибку - что делает этот код? Каково его назначение? Как это использовать потом будете? Ну и версию .NET укажите, от этого может зависеть ответ. Убрал метку `javascript`, потому что вам явно не нужен ответ на `javascript`.

Comment: @aepot _потому что вам явно не нужен ответ на javascript_ - с другой стороны, знание javascript не помешает

Comment: `BitConverter.ToString` возвращает результат в верхнем регистре, а сравниваешь ты со строкой в нижнем.

Comment: ну и кроме того ты разные строки хэшируешь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

оператор [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) в js, полностью удаляет ключ из объект, поэтому после выполнения строки

```
delete j["signature"]
```

в `j` не будет поля `signature` и, соответственно такой подстроки не будет в строке для хеширования.

В тоже время, в коде C# в строку явно добавляется `signature{signature}`, несмотря на то, что значение signature перед вызовом очищается.

Таким образом нужно исправить `ToString` удалив лишнюю часть

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"amount{amount.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))}item_id{item_id}unique_id{unique_id}username{username}";
}
```

Также стоит обратить внимание, что `BitConverter.ToString` вернет строку в верхнем регистре, в то время как сравнение производится со строкой в нижнем. Для решения можно привести строку к нижнему регистру, например с помощью [`ToLower`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=net-6.0) либо воспользоваться регистронезависимым сравнением.

Comment: Автор вообще не использует метод `HashString`.

Comment: @aepot. да, в этом случае второй пункт не актуален, для текущей версии, но проблема со сравнением остается при его использовании

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за ответ. я уже понял в чем проблема и решил ее. aepot благодарю вас за помощь.